# How to Subset Pandas Dataframe with entire rows of each Unique Values of each columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a pandas dataframe like

```
data = [['M', 10, 'red','apple'], 
        ['F', 15, 'blue','orange'], 
        ['M', 14, 'blue','apple'],
        ['M', 14, 'blue','apple'], 
        ['F', 14, 'blue','apple'], 
        ['M', 14, 'red',''], 
        ['M', 14, 'blue','banana'], 
        ['', 14, 'blue','apple']] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Gender', 'Age', 'Color','Fruit'])
```

Here Gender has 3 levels, M,F,missing, Color has 2 levels, red,blue, Fruit has 4 levels apple, orange, banana, missing, numerics doesn't matter

So total 9 levels in entire dataframe,

I wish to subset One row for each Level,
For example

My resultant dataframe will be like

```
result_data = [['M', 10, 'red','apple'], 
               ['F', 15, 'blue','orange'], 
               ['M', 14, 'red',''], 
               ['M', 14, 'blue','banana'], 
               ['', 14, 'blue','apple']]
```

So I got One row for each category, M,F,missing_Gender,red,blue,apple,orange,banana,missing_Fruit

My Dropping Criteria is
All categories in the 3 rows that is dropped were available for us in result_data

Comment: Can you explain more why `['M', 14, 'blue','apple'],
        ['M', 14, 'blue','apple'], 
        ['F', 14, 'blue','apple'],` is removed? what means one row?

Comment: the question is bit confusing ,what is the criteria of dropping the rows ?

Comment: ['M', 14, 'blue','apple'] from this row we have M,blue,apple available in another row, like wise all categories in other dropped two rows is available in the result data, In whole all categories in dropped rows were available for us in result_data

Comment: the close is `df1 = df.drop_duplicates(['Color', 'Fruit'], keep='last')` - but it remove duplicates by last 2 columns, not sure if need it. Because if remove duplicates by 3 columns like `df2 = df.drop_duplicates(['Gender','Color', 'Fruit'], keep='last')` get different output.

Comment: drop_duplicate works well, Thanks

Comment: @jezrael, if we do that In a for loop passing each column, drop_duplicates works well and good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could you `DataFrame.drop_duplicates()`, refer to [this documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

Using the option of `subset` and `keep`, you could achieve what you want, i.e.

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Gender','Color','Fruit'], keep=False)
```

Basically, the parameter `subset` contains your definition of unique in your data, for the example above, you define unique data by those 3 columns.

The parameter `keep` refers to preserving the duplicated data. This allows you to keep `first` or `last` element and also setting it to `False` means dropping all the duplicates completely.

For example with the definition of duplicates = data with unique `gender` and `fruit`:

```
data=[['M', 14, 'blue','apple'],
      ['M', 20, 'red','apple'], 
      ['F', 14, 'blue','apple'], 
      ['F', 14, 'red','apple'],
      ['F', 20, 'blue','apple']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Gender', 'Age', 'Color','Fruit']) 

# The code below will result in 
# 'M', 14, 'blue','apple'
# 'F', 14, 'blue','apple' 
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Gender','Fruit'], keep='first')

# The code below will result in 
# 'M', 20, 'red','apple'
# 'F', 20, 'blue','apple'
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Gender','Fruit'], keep='last')

# The code below will result in empty, since no duplicates
# are kept
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Gender','Fruit'], keep=False)
```

Hope this helps.